# Telerik mvc Grid in edit mode not passing properties

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a telerik grid in my mvc application with a edit button.

When I click on this button I get another template from SharedTemplates based on the same model of the grid view.

In my editor template, if I declare a field using this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(a => a.Order)
```

Html generated:

```
<input class="text-box single-line valid" id="Order" name="Order" type="text" value="000020">
```

As you can see, I got the order value from the grid when I clicked on the edit button. But if I declare the same field not using the model, like this:

```
 <input type="text" id="Order" name="Order"  style="width: 100px; background-color: lightgrey" />
```

Html generated:

```
<input type="text" id="Order" name="Order" style="width: 100px; background-color:         lightgrey">
```

Basically, the question is: Why if I put   @Html.EditorFor(a => a.Order) I get the order value when I click edit, and I cannot get the order value when I use the

> input type="text" id="Order" name="Order"  style="width: 100px; background-color: lightgrey" />

Comment: Your last two code snippets are identical. Can you please include the code you use when declaring "the same field not using the model"?

Comment: @QuetiM.Porta, the `<input type="text" id="Order" name="Order"  style="width: 100px; background-color: lightgrey" />` is the code snippet in the view. When im debuging, i get this html generated `<input type="text" id="Order" name="Order" style="width: 100px; background-color: lightgrey">` , without the value parameter.